# Clark Kent captured by Aliens who think he's a typical Earthman

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman

I realize this may be a long shot, but I distinctly remember reading this comic, I think in a reprint anthology, probably in the early 70s. It was almost certainly a Silver Age reprint.

The gist is, nasty aliens are planning to invade Earth, but first they grab a random guy from a random city, who just happens to be Clark Kent. Unusually, Superman stays in character as Clark, and as the aliens fruitlessly subject him to various experiments and weapons, he keeps insisting, "No, I'm just average. Or a little below. Ask anybody."

Of course, the aliens decide that Earth is *way* too tough for them, return Clark with apologies, and skedaddle.

Has anyone got any idea who wrote or drew it, where I can find this story, (either the original or a reprint), or a way to narrow it down? Or even a clue as to where to start hunting?

Comment: Action Comics or possibly Superman's Pal Jimmy Olsen?

Comment: This is almost the exact plot (minus Superman) of Asimov's "[Victory Unintentional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_Unintentional)"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, in my research on this question I've found a few different things that corroborate that maybe a Superman comic exists with that story (which is very similar to "Victory Unintentional.") Such as this [comment](https://dochermes.livejournal.com/386891.html?thread=1523275#t1523275):

> Wasn't there at least one Silver Age comics story wherein Superman deters an alien invasion in similar fashion — never outright lying, but forbearing to correct their misconception that he's a representative Earthling?

But, I haven't been able to find an issue that has that premise. However, I did find the same story in "The Adventures of Superboy" episode "Operation Counter Invasion" circa 1966.

> The U.S. army gets ready to attack a strange UFO that has landed in the desert. Superboy convinces them to give him time to handle the situation peacefully. **Landing near the aliens, they are amazed and concerned at the powers and abilities that Superboy and Krypto display, and mistakenly convince themselves that their coming invasion of Earth will fail if all earthlings have these powers.** [Big Cartoon Database](https://www.bcdb.com/cartoon/25452-Operation-Counter-Invasion)

Here is some dialogue from the episode:

> **Alien**: How is it you and your dog fly, Earthling, with no visible motive power?
> **Superboy**: Doesn't everyone?

He demonstrates super strength and invulnerability (as they attack him and shoot him with a ray gun) and convinces the aliens to abandon their plan to invade Earth.